# Kotlin coroutines Unresolved reference: onComplete

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The previous functions are executed, but the following functions report "Unresolved reference"

```
@WorkerThread
    @JvmSynthetic
    @SuspensionFunction
    suspend inline fun <T : BaseResponse> ApiResponse<T>.request(
        noinline onStart: suspend () -> Unit = {},
        noinline onSuccess: suspend ApiResponse.Success<T>.() -> Unit = {},
        noinline onFailure: suspend ApiResponse.Failure.Failure<T>.() -> Unit = {},
        noinline onException: suspend ApiResponse.Failure.Exception<T>.() -> Unit = {},
        noinline onServerRejectedRequest: suspend ApiResponse.Failure.ServerRejectedRequest<T>.() -> Unit = {},
        noinline onComplete: suspend () -> Unit = {},
    ) = flow {
        this@request.suspendOnSuccess {
            response?.let { response ->
                onSuccess.invoke(this)
                emit(response)
            }
        }.suspendOnFailure {
            onFailure.invoke(this)
        }.suspendOnException {
            onException.invoke(this)
        }.suspendOnServerRejectedRequest {
            onServerRejectedRequest.invoke(this)
        }
    }.onStart { onStart.invoke() }.onCompletion { onComplete.invoke() }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
        .collect()
```

when I called like that, then unresolved reference: onComplete

```kotlin
     repo.login(uniqueNumber).request {
                onComplete = { // -> Unresolved reference
                     //TODO something
                }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your BaseResposne and ApiResponse class ?

Comment: Pretty sure you mean `request(onComplete = {`, i.e. `(` instead of `{`.